# nested route in express api

Tags: node.js, express, routes, nested

i'm trying to create the following route in my API:

```
/users/compare
```

The problem is.. i can't, because i already have:

```
/users/:slug
```

So.. when i try to access the `/users/compare`, i will access the `/users/:slug`

Can i resolve this?

```
app.get('/users/:slug', ......);
app.get('/users/compare', ......);
```

One route is for create user, and other is to confirm login credentials.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain a bit about what is going on here.

Routes are evaluated in the order you declare them.  If you have overlapping routes (where more than one route could match a given URL), then the order you declare them is very important as the first one that matches it will handle it and the others will not get a shot at at.

As you probably realize the route:

```
app.get('/users/:slug', ......);
```

will match `/users/anything`.  So, that pretty much means that anything that starts with `/users/` will match this route.  If you put that route first, before your `app.get('/users/compare', ......);` route, then `/users/:slug` will match the URL `/users/compare` and it will handle that request.  Because of that, your route for `/users/compare` will never get called.

If you put the `/users/compare` first, then it will get the first crack at the URL `/users/compare` and it will work appropriately.

In general, it is better to design a URL scheme that does not have these types of conflicts.  I can't say you should never do it because sometimes there are perfectly fine exceptions that just require you to order your routes appropriately, but in general you would like to avoid it if there is a different/better way to organize your URL design that does not create this conflict.

I don't know exactly what you're doing here, but perhaps you should be doing something like this:

```
app.get('/userscmd/compare', ......);
app.get('/users/:slug', ......);
```

or:

```
app.get('/userscompare', ......);
app.get('/users/:slug', ......);
```

---

You can also do something like this:

```
app.get('/users/:slug', function(req, res) {
    var param = req.params.slug;
    if (param === "compare") {
        // special slug word
    } else {
        // regular slug
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....The order of routes should help solve your problem (though it's not a good practice for maintainability)

First add this route

app.get('/users/compare', ......);

Later add this route

app.get('/users/:slug', ......);

Comment: I'm going to try.. but how should i do if is not a good practice?